# Cookies won't set?

Tags: php, html, cookies

So, I'm making a simple website blocked script, and in the end it will just say website blocked, and will foreword someone to a page like igoogle, with weather, news, and such, but I can't create a cookie at all, in any script.  I put the create cookie script in the same page as the read cookie script.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>***WEBSITE BLOCKED***</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$expire=3600;
echo $expire;
setcookie("user2112", "Justin Marmorato", $expire);
if (isset($_COOKIE["user2112"]))
echo "Welcome " . $_COOKIE["user2112"] . "!<br>";
else
echo "Welcome guest!<br>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Heres the output every time
3600Welcome guest!

Comment: your `setcookie` needs to be called before any output starts, it doesn't look like your using output buffering so your cookie will not be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it...
You should set

```
$expire = time()+3600;
```

not

```
$expire = 3600;
```

OK...
I tested it and it works...

Comment: Thanks, It worked!  Unfornitionatly, I joined today and it won't let me up-vote your post.  I will as soon as I can.

Comment: ok No problem
just see my question and let me know if you can help me...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299095/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-variable-help-needed

Comment: Niraj: Asking for votes to get reputation is generally frowned-upon. Instead, I suggest you invest your time into writing complete, carefully-researched posts to give complete and correct answers.